# dynamic TextView in android appwidget

Tags: android

I want to add dynamic TextView to my appwidget but cant find the solution to do it.
In normal view, I use `findViewById`, but i guess its not supported in appwidget.

Here is my code:

```
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
this.list2 = populatelist();             
int widgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 0);

AppWidgetManager appWidgetMan = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),R.layout.mywidgetlayout);
LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylinear);
for (int i = 0; i <= list2.size() ; i++)
{
    TextView myText = new TextView(this);
    myText.setText(list2.get(i));
    lin.addView(myText);
}
appWidgetMan.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
```

and my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mylinear"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="0.1dp">

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/widgetBtn" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0.1" 
        android:src="@drawable/smile_icon" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    </ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

This line gives error  on `findViewById`:

```
LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylinear);
```

Comment: wht error you are getting?

Comment: @niteshgoel , this "findViewById" -> The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get linearlayout for remoteviews like this

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout1_1);
```

and then settext to textview within that layout

```
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textviewId, "YOUR TEXT HERE");
```

hope this will help!!

Comment: thanks for help but i can settext with no problem , the problem is im going to make dynamic textbox in my appwidget view

Comment: I think you can use `remoteViews.addView()` method

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mywidgetlayout, null);

    LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout)layout.findViewById(R.id.mylinear);
```